# How to draw with semiology in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, plot

I have below the following information:

```
Q = [16,32,64,128,256,512,1024];
y = [9     9     9     9     5     0     0]*0.25;
y1 = [45    37    25    21     5     0     0]*0.25;
```

After multiplication with 0.25, they became as below

**y**
[image]

**y2**
[image]

and the above Q is the same

[image]

when I use the **semiology plot** function as below

```
semilogy(Q,y,Q,y1)
xlabel('Q oder');
ylabel('Coverage area m^2');
grid on;
```

I saw the x and y axis are different than what I have in Q and Y as shown below. Does this make sense? Do I apply it in the wrong way? If yes, May you assist me?

[image]

Comment: Where `y` is 0, no point can be drawn, since log(0) is at minus infinity. I suspect that you intended to draw the x-axis as logarithmic, not the y axis. Use `semilogx`.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Yes dear. It has been solved by using semilogx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [`xticks`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xticks.html).

```
xticks(Q)
```

You may also be interested in [`xticklabels`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xticklabels.html).

I don't have MATLAB here so I can't illustrate it, but it is what you are after.